# How do I install El Capitan on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: windows, macbook, osx-el-capitan

I have a MacBook Pro 2011. I have totally formatted it and installed Win7. Also I have made two partitions (Not bootcamp method) now there's no trace of Mac OS in this MacBook pro.

Now I want to install El Capitan. I have downloaded a DMG file from  torrent which is 5.6GB.

Will it work if i burn the DMG file to a USB using transmac and boot it?

Or do I need something else ?

Some say we need to change the USB stick into GPT format to make it bootable in  Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Your drive must be formatted as a Mac OS Extended (Journaled) volume with a GUID Partition Table. (Follow this tutorial to properly format the drive if you're using OS X Yosemite or older. If you're using OS X El Capitan, use these instructions.)

http://www.macworld.com/article/2981585/operating-systems/how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-10-11-el-capitan-installer-drive.html

This macworld article lists everything from start to finish what you need to do from the download to installing to partitioning your drive.

Next time, follow common practices with the tools provided from Apple for a dualboot enviroment.

Comment: Hi I really appreciate for the help. But how can I formated it as Mac OS extended ? Because right now I'm running win7 on the Mac. Can you tell me if the El captain installer has tools to format and repartition the disk ?

Comment: You're more than likely going to have to format everything and start completly over running the OS X El Capitan, installing that and then configuring the dual boot bootcamp and then installing Windows.